# Weird keyboard issues after upgrading to 20.10: Del key doesn’t work and layout reverts to QWERTY

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, 20.10

I installed Ubuntu with the [Neo keyboard layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neo_(keyboard_layout)#Neo_2) (think Dvorak for the German language) as the default from installation (a few years ago).
It thus always was the keyboard layout for TTYs, login, and user sessions without further ado. I am usually using I3 as a window manager.

Yesterday, I upgraded from 20.04 to 20.10 and now I face two problems, which I assume to be related:

- Neo still is the layout in the TTYs and the login window, but once I log in, the layout reverts to QWERTY for no apparent reason.
  I can fix this with `setxkbmap de neo`, but having this automatically run by my I3 config doesn’t work.
- Whenever I press <kbd>Del</kbd>, it doesn’t work, but instead the respective control character (007F) is inserted or nothing happens (depending on the program I am running). For example, in URXVT, the character is shown somewhere on the screen, irrespective of where the actual terminal is:

  [image]

  This is happens even if I do not change the keyboard layout after logging in.
  Moreover, this also happens, if I use a key combination from Neo that makes the “key” more accessible to a normal finger position, so it has nothing to do with what physical key is pressed. No other key appears to have such an issue.

Both issues occur in several display managers, namely LXDM, GDM3 and LightDM.
The issues also happen if I launch an LXDE session, so they are not specific to I3.
Both issues do not occur with a freshly created user.

#### Diagnostics

- The output of `setxkbmap -print -verbose 10` directly after logging in is:

  ```
  Setting verbose level to 10
  locale is C
  Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
  Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
  Success.
  Applied rules from evdev:
  rules:      evdev
  model:      thinkpad
  layout:     us
  Trying to build keymap using the following components:
  keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
  types:      complete
  compat:     complete
  symbols:    pc+us+inet(evdev)
  geometry:   thinkpad(us)
  xkb_keymap {
      xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
      xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
      xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
      xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+inet(evdev)" };
      xkb_geometry  { include "thinkpad(us)"  };
  };
  ```
- `/etc/default/keyboard`

  ```
  XKBLAYOUT="de"
  BACKSPACE="guess"
  XKBMODEL="thinkpad"
  XKBVARIANT="neo"
  XKBOPTIONS=""
  ```
- `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources` (also directly after logging in):

  ```
  [('xkb', 'de+neo')]
  ```

Comment: Since you don't see the issue with new users, there is apparently something in your `$HOME` which confuses i3. Suppose you need help by somebody who is familiar with i3, unless you are not able to figure it out yourself.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson: It’s not related to I3. See my edit.

Comment: I see. And according to the latest edit you set Neo both system wide and in the dconf value which determines the layout when logging in to e.g. a GNOME session. My conclusion is that you should 'clean up' your `$HOME`. Apparently you have tried several different DMs and windows managers, and doing so may cause issues once in a while.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson: It seems that IBus was at least one of the culprits. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seemed to be two separate issues after all.

- The issue with <kbd>del</kbd> ceased after I removed `.cache` and some other dot files of programs I don’t use anymore. It could be also something different.
- Afterwards, I fixed the issue of the keyboard layout reverting by `ibus-setup` → *Advanced* → *Use system keyboard layout,* which was unchecked for some reason.